# Pass Ascending/Descending option to uasort()?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How would I switch the sort order between ascending/descending in the following function? All it does is order a multidimensional array by a chosen field, and then by title.

```
$sortby = 'date';
$orderby = 'asc';

function sort($a, $b)
{
    $retval = strnatcmp($a[$sortby], $b[$sortby]);
    if(!$retval) return strnatcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    return $retval;
}

uasort($jobs, 'sort');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reverse option - you'd have to create a new sort function that returns the negative of your sort function.

Simple but inefficient:

```
function rsort($a, $b)
{
    return -1 * sort($a, $b);
}
```

Comment: how about

function rsort($a, $b) { return sort($b, $a); }

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a>$b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 5.2, 'b' => 2.2, 'c' => 1.2, 'd' => 1.2,'f' => 5.5, 'g' => 1.2, 'h' => 6.2);
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: i mean return ($a>$b) big to small and for small to big ($a<$b)